# Downloaded file from github is considered binary file?

Tags: git

I'm wondering if its possible to download a binary file (which is actually real code) and convert it into readable characters?

I believe it is UTF-16 and when I try to convert to UTF-6 it shows some characters but not all.

Any idea if I can get this binary file specifically to be converted to a readable file?

link: removed

Comment: UTF-6? Exotic.. Anyway, why wouldn't you just download the code as a zip file from here: https://github.com/rajiteh/cse3221_project_benchmarker/archive/master.zip ?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: UTF-16, not UTF-6 -- but that's not what the file is.

Comment: If you use Linux (or cygwin) the "strings" tool locate strings inside a binary file.  This may be 8-bit only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not source code, it's an ELF executable, as you can verify with:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://github.com/rajiteh/cse3221_project_benchmarker/blob/master/bin/fbq?raw=true | file -
```

So it can't be converted to readable text in any meaningful way.

If you meant to decompile/disassemble it to recover the source code, that's a different process, for which you will need specialized tools.

Comment: Does that mean its encrypted from other people accessing it? Also, what specialized tools do you think would work? Would it involve decrypting?

Comment: No, it's not encrypted, it's just a binary format which is meant to be read by your computer, not you. The easiest way to get the source code (C, I guess) would be asking the owner of the repository. If you want to try and reconstruct it by yourself, google for "decompiler" and "disassembler". It will require a few technical skills, though.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that, I will try using hex-rays decompiler and boomerang decompiler to see if it works out.

Comment: @geforce: It's a binary executable file, consisting mostly of machine code instructions. What do you hope to accomplish by converting it to some printable format?

Comment: @geforce decompilation is not an automatic process, it requires some interaction from your part to get what might not even resemble the original source code (for instance, all comments will be missing). Asking the owner of the repo will be much easier.

Comment: Alright, I will try that since he does go to my university I will just see what he says because this source code will be a great reference for me to implement my multilevel feedback queue in c.

Comment: hah! Problem solved, I got the file I needed in the repository thank you guys for the help.